# Parallelize (with tensorflow for GPU) the preprocessing of images

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, gpu, video-processing

I am training a model to classify pictures as having or not having a specific object (I'm currently using a red pen as an example, but it could be any other thing). I am generating my own training data (images) as follows: I record a video, in several environments, where sometimes the red pen appears. I then have a little script that plays the video and let's me set which frames have the pen (with some key presses), returning a 1-D Boolean array with a size equal to the number of frames (the true values are the frames with the object). Now here is my problem: I want to resize these frames and save them as jpeg, the name stating to which class they belong with an id appended (like "nopen_123.jpeg").

I've been able to do this using cv2's `read()` `resize()` and `imwrite()`, in a sequential fashion. However, this is rather slow, considering I'm planning to use this method in very long videos. I was wondering if it would be possible to upgrade this pipeline (maybe using tensorflow and the gpu) to parallelize the reading of frames, the resizing and the saving (I'm not sure whether is possible to save images in batches), since at this point operations over frames are really independent. Anything will be helpful, I'm really lost here.